# Awesome WM - Chatty (Java application) bypass dimension properties from rc.lua

Tags: linux, lua, archlinux, awesome-wm

Chatty is a java application to chat in Twitch (streaming platform) from the desktop.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that Chatty always starts with specifics X, Y, width and height properties.

```
{ rule = { class = "chatty-Chatty" },
  properties = {
    width = 267, 
    height = 223, 
    x = 1575, 
    y = 774
  },
},
```

The X and Y properties work just fine, wherever I move the window if I closed and open it again it appears in my desired position. However for some reason I fail to acknowledge Chatty doesn't care about the width and height properties, it always opens with the last geometry.

Chatty itself have a config file but there isn't anything related to width and height dimensions.

I'm on Arch, and the only WM I have is Awesome.

PD: One weird thing is that every time I'm changing the window size it also moves, always in a bottom right direction. This is annoying but not a problem, I'm mentioning this just in case it is related to the possible issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because they client resize itself after the rules are executed (which would be a bug in your app or Java). In any case, you can do:

```
client.disconnect_signal("request::geometry", awful.ewmh.client_geometry_requests)
```

to turn off the client ability to resize themselves.

In AwesomeWM git-master version, you can use the permission API to deny the `"client" -> "geometry" -> "ewmh"` permission per client.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I want to add that code to my rc.lua but I wonder in what part it is referencing the chatty client? is it that I need to replace the 'client' part with 'chatty-Chatty' in my case?

Comment: Pace it at the bottom of `rc.lua`. This disables the ability for clients to resize themselves globally (not only for your chat app). There is almost no valid use case where this feature is useful. Disabling it only makes things better.